# How to calculate the reference Gibbs energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-diagram

I want to calculate the Zr-O diagram based on the data from this [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S036459160400032X). The article contains 4 tables with data for:

- pure elements,
- stoichiometric phases,
- phases of solutions,
- gases.

How should I calculate $^oG$ for these kinds of phases? For example: Can I calculate $^oG\rm(O_2Zr_1<fcc_C1>)$ as a polynomial from the table or I must calculate $^oG(\rm{ O_2Zr_1<fcc\_C1>})+\it^oG\rm(Zr_1<hcp\_A3>)+0.5\it^oG\rm(O2<G>)$
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you venture further into the phase diagram calculation literature you will find quite a variety of treatments by different authors (sadly perhaps).

The main approach sticks to using either the absolute thermodynamic data for elements in different phases as tabulated by [A.T. Dinsdale](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/036459169190030N). The other is to pick a particular phase (usually the one stable at STP) as the reference, with $G(T) = 0$, and use the differences in $G$ for the other phases. Dinsdale provides this data as well for the usually chosen standard phase. (For P, the white phase is taken as the reference by convention, which is not the STP stable phase.)

Sometimes, however, for various reasons authors will choose a mixed approach, treating some phases relative to the reference phases, and some as absolute. In binary compounds the latter is often chosen when the Neumann-Kopp estimate of the heat capacity doesn't work particularly well. In that case one needs to use the known differences between absolute and relative elemental phases and adjust accordingly.

In the case of your particular paper, the authors have taken a mixed approach, with further confusion in some terminology. In Table 1, the first line is for liquid oxygen relative to O$_{2}$ in the gas phase. However, the value listed in Table 1 corresponds to the value in Dinsdale of oxygen liquid relative to $1 \over 2$O$_{2}$(gas). Next, the Uranium and Zirconium phases (solid allotropes and liquid) are all listed as referenced to SER (Standard Element Reference), yet the values entered into the table are those from Dinsdale for the absolute phases. The multiple lines are for different temperature ranges (clearer in Dinsdale).

For Table 2, the binary compounds, I would interpret those as being absolute Gibbs functions, even though they also claim to be referenced to SER. Given they need to use all the terms in the parameterization of $G$, experience says they are absolute.

Table 3 has the interaction parameters for mixtures, and those do not matter whether the reference phases are absolute or relative.

Table 4 is a bit ugly (but dealing with all the species in a gas phase can be quite ugly indeed). My take, again, is that those are absolute values. Again, each different line under a given species is a different temperature range - the first is from 298.15K up to whatever the temperature listed for the next line is. The main difficulty then lies in how to connect liquid oxygen, O(L), in Table 1, to O$_{2}$ in the gas phase. I'm particularly confused since the values given in Table 4 for O$_{2}$ are close to, but not quite, the absolute G values listed in Dinsdale for two times $1 \over 2$O$_{2}$(gas). Seems a bit odd to use the Dinsdale relative value for the liquid, but not use his values for the gas phase. But, perhaps there are some known discrepancies in the gas values...

So, given that (nearly) everything is listed as an absolute G, feel free to continue to keep everything as absolute. You will have to use the O$_{2}$ function to get the liquid values though. In any event, just be consistent. The common tangents of phase equilibria don't care what your reference state is, they just need them to be the same for all phases.

In the end I made a rough draft of the paper. This is what I have, fairly unpolished:

[image: O-Zr calculated phase diagram]

I skipped the fcc phase and clearly I've got something wrong with the bcc Zr phase, which together change the shape of the hcp Zr phase. For the monoclinic and tetragonal ZrO$_{2}$ line compounds, I divided the formula in Chevalier by 3 to get it per-atom (not per compound unit). For the hcp and bcc, one has to add appropriately the Zr(hcp_A3) or Zr(bcc_A2) formulas, as well as an appropriate representation of $1 \over 2$O$_{2}$(gas) to the compound G given in Table 3 (so Zr_hcp+0.5*O_gas in hcp, Zr_bcc+3 O_gas in bcc). For simplicity I used the Dinsdale functionals for oxygen, not what is in the paper, which may also impact some phase boundaries.

The liquid is an Associate Liquid Model. An associate liquid comprises three (or more!) entities. There are the two elements of the binary diagram, call them $A$ and $B$, and then some compound $A_i B_j$. Whether this compound has a distinct identity or not is not important – there is some preference for $i$ atoms of $A$ and $j$ atoms of $B$ to hang around together for long enough to be called an entity. Now, at some given concentration, one needs to determine the numbers of $A$, $B$, and $A_i B_j$ in the liquid that minimize the Gibbs free energy. At a fixed composition this yields one free parameter, the number of $AB$ entities (I’ll skip the subscripts for now) – there is some maximum possible number, and certainly the number of $AB$ entities could be zero.
Each entity has a Gibbs free energy of that entity as a pure liquid, so there is a term like:

$G = n_A G_A + n_B G_B + n_{AB} G_{AB}$

The entropy is easily extended:

$S = RT (n_A ln(n_A/n_{tot}) + n_B ln(n_B/n_{tot}) + n_{AB} ln(n_{AB}/n_{tot}))$

with

$n_{tot} = n_A + n_B + n_{AB}$

Then there are mixing terms between the entities, just like the normal mixing terms in regular solutions. Here there could be terms for (O,Zr), (O, O$_{2}$Zr), and (O$_{2}$Zr,Zr), but only the last was used. It is also possible that a ternary term could have been needed. In this case, the mixing term looks only like:

$({n_{AB}n_B \over n_{tot}}) (L^{0}_{O_2 Zr,Zr} + {n_{AB}-n_B \over n_{tot}} L^{1}_{O_2 Zr,Zr} +  ({n_{AB}-n_B \over n_{tot}})^{2} L^{2}_{O_2 Zr,Zr}) $

One can choose $n$'s such that $n_A = x_A - i n_{AB}$ and similarly $n_B = (1-x_A) - j n_{AB}$ for an $A_i B_j$ entity with $x_A$ being the compositional fraction of element A.  So, vary $n_{AB}$ across its possible range for each $x_A$ to find the minimum Gibbs free energy, and construct the curve that way. I have (ugly) Python code that does that by brute force, but it goes pretty quickly.

So, some (ugly, not well commented) code:

```
def OZr_liq(x): 
    def gliq(nA,nB,nAB): # A = O, B = Zr, AB = O2Zr
        gA = OGas()+O_liq() # values from Dinsdale
        gB = ZrHcp()+Zr_liq() # values from Dinsdale
        def O2ZrLiq(): # values from the paper
            if(T < 1478):
                g = -1.03167162E6+3.919331E2*T-6.962180E1*T*np.log(T)-3.7656E-3*T*T+7.0291E5/T
            elif(T < 2208.):
                g = -1.03502534E6+4.5083609E2*T-7.81E1*T*np.log(T)
            else:
                g = -1.08338054E6+6.41362639E2*T-100.*T*np.log(T)
            return(g)
        gAB = O2ZrLiq()
        LA = 0.0 # O,Zr
        LB = 0.0 # O,O2Zr
        LC0 = -23653.07 # O2Zr,Zr
        LC1 = -2599.65
        LC2 = -36782.35
        ntot = nA + nB + nAB
        return(nA*gA + nB*gB + nAB*gAB + R*T*(nA*np.log(nA/ntot) + nB*np.log(nB/ntot) + nAB*np.log(nAB/ntot)) + 
                (nAB*nB/ntot)*(LC0+(nAB-nB)*LC1/ntot+(nAB-nB)*(nAB-nB)*LC2/ntot/ntot))
    return(ALM(x,gliq,2.,1.))
```

This defines the Gibbs free energy as a function of the 'number' of A, B, and AB entities present. The Associate Liquid Model then takes a vector of compositions (of A in atomic percent), this free energy function, and the composition of the AB entity (here 2:1). ALM is

```
def ALM(xA,F,A,B): # Associate Liquid Model
    """ ALM - Associate Liquid Model """
    """ xA is an array with composition of A across the phase diagram """
    """ F(nA,nB,nAB) calculates the Gibbs free energy """
    """ A is how many atoms of constituant A makes the AB associate """
    """ B is how many atoms of constituant B makes the AB associate """
    
    ABmax = np.minimum(xA/A,(1.0-xA)/B)
    
    ix = np.arange(0,len(xA),dtype=int)
    
    nAB = ABmax[None,:].T*np.linspace(0.00001,0.99999,100) # scoping study
    nA = xA[None,:].T - A*nAB
    nB = (1.0-xA[None,:].T)-B*nAB
    
    D = F(nA,nB,nAB)
    
    Dprev = np.amin(D,axis=1)
    
    num = 50
    
    n = 0
    while (n < 10):
        n = n+1
        iD1 = D.argmin(axis=1)
    
        newMin = np.maximum(iD1-1,0)
        newMin = nAB[ix,newMin]
        newMax = np.minimum(iD1+1,len(nAB[1,])-1)
        newMax = nAB[ix,newMax]
    
        nAB =  np.array([np.linspace(i,j,num) for i,j in zip(newMin,newMax)])
        nA = xA[None,:].T - A*nAB
        nB = (1.0-xA[None,:].T)-B*nAB
    
        D = F(nA,nB,nAB)
    
        Dnext = np.amin(D,axis=1)
    
        DDnext = np.sum(np.abs(Dprev-Dnext))/len(xA)
        # print(n,DDnext)
        if(DDnext < 1.0E-10):
            break
        Dprev = Dnext

    return(Dprev)
```

Frankly, this just does a brute force (binary like) search - evaluate the free energy across the composition of nAB from 0 to the maximum value at a given $x_A$ at 100 points, find the minimum value, contract the search space to be around that point, evaluate again, and keep doing it until the answer doesn't change much. Actually happens pretty quickly, but still ugly...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was very helpful! However, I have not achieved success. I tried to calculate the envelope of the Gibbs energy and it turned out that the stoichiometric phases are modeled incorrectly. All but one are located above the envelope curve. In addition, the Gibbs energies of stoichiometric phases differ by orders of magnitude from the Gibbs energies of solution phases. What do you think this could be related to?

Comment: Right, you are now further debugging the assessment, again not uncommon. Their earlier paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022311598004504?via%3Dihub) 
 may give some additional insight. Welcome to debugging Calphad... I have not programmed up O-Zr, and am not going to do it today (real work to do), so good luck.

Comment: Oh, it's not an easy job! Thank you so much! If you suddenly decide to program O-Zr or O-U, I will be very grateful to you!

Comment: Can you please tell me how you calculated the liquid phase?

Comment: More precisely, how to calculate $^oG$ in an associative fluid model?

Comment: The basics of the associate model are covered in both Lukas' and Saunder's books on Calphad. By having a liquid composed of O, Zr, and O2Zr entities you now have to minimize G as a function of numbers of each entity at a given composition. This is fairly easy to brute force. I suppose I could add a section at the end of the answer if I have time.

Comment: That would be good!  I have been successful in modeling O2/2, ZrO2(TET), ZrO2(MON), FCC_C1, HCP_A3, BCC_A2 phases.  I divided the formulas $G^α_M$ into $\sum_{A,s} a^s*b^s_{Ai}$

Comment: number of sites multiplied by stoichiometric phase coefficients across all sublattices

Comment: So, can I use this formula?
$G = y_{Zr} {}^oG_{Zr}+y_{ZrO2}{}^oG_{ZrO2}+y_{O} {}^oG_{O}+\\+RT(y_{Zr}ln(y_{Zr})+y_{ZrO2}ln(y_{ZrO2})+y_{O}ln(y_{O}))+\\
+y_{ZrO2} y_{Zr} (L^0_{ZrO2,Zr}+L^1_{ZrO2,Zr}(y_{ZrO2}-y_{Zr})+L^2_{ZrO2,Zr}(y_{ZrO2}-y_{Zr})^2)$, 
where$ y_{i} = n_{i} / n_{tot}, i = Zr,ZrO2,O$.

Comment: The first line can't use the relative ratios - it has to be the number of entities with a given liquid free energy. The rest (entropy and mixing).

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't fully understand the method of calculating the liquid phase. You said that you have a code for calculating this phase. Could you attach it to the answer? This could be of serious help.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I figured out how to calculate this chart. My problem was that I did not minimize the Gibbs energy of the liquid phase. I have modeled all phases within CEF. I calculated the Gibbs molar energy using the formula $G_m = G_M/M$ and everything came together perfectly. At the moment I have difficulty minimizing the Gibbs energy of the liquid phase. I use matlab for calculations. At some points of the grid, minimization does not give a good result. I have tried interpolating the $G_m$ to these points, but this creates false miscibility gaps.

Comment: @EgorM.T. - ok, you have some ugly code to try to figure out here...